# Bash solution to extract part of FASTA header

Tags: bash

I have a FASTA file of the form

```
ABCNA929-08|Lymantria_dispar_dispar|COI-5P|MF131764
```

and I want to extract everything before the first "|" delimiter, i.e., ABCNA929-08

This is easiest in Bash, but I'm not a frequent user, so I am unsure of the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using AWK:

```
awk -F"|" '/\|/ {print $1}' file.fasta
```

Explanation: using "|" as a delimiter, search for lines containing the "|" character (FASTA headers only, not the >ATCGA...etc) and print the first field (i.e. everything up to the first "|").

Or, with bash:

```
while read -r line; do [[ $line =~ '|' ]] && echo ${line/|*/}; done < file.fasta
```

Does that solve your problem?

Comment: Thanks. It works like a charm! What if I want to remove the `>` as well? Would I need  to include `&& $line=~ '>'`  within the `[[ ]]`?

Comment: I think you would need an extra step, i.e. `while read -r line; do tmp=${line/|*/}; [[ $line =~ '|' ]] && echo ${tmp:1}; done < file.fasta` (or, with AWK, `awk -F"[>|]" '/\|/ {print $2}' file.fasta`)

Comment: Yes... this works too.

Answer (score 1):

Would you please try the following:

```
sed -E 's/^>?([^|]+).*/\1/' file.fasta
```

Output:

```
ABCNA929-08
```

It will work with or without the leading `>` character in the FASTA header.

- `^>?` matches zero or one `>` character at the beginning of the line.
- `([^|]+)` matches a sequence of any characters other than `|`.
  The matched substring is captured as `\1`.
- `.*` matches the remaining characters to be removed.
- The substitution `s/^>?([^|]+).*/\1/` removes characters
  other than the matched substring as `\1`.